# jQuery UI selectmenus breaks layout

Tags: jquery-ui, select, select-menu

I am using this plugin: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html (dropdown style)

And it is working well but when i add a selectmenu at the bottom of my page then this happends:

[image]

How can i fix this that when the selectmenu is on the bottom that the dropdown comes above instead of under?

The JS i use:

```
$('select').not("select.multiple").selectmenu({
    style: 'dropdown',
    transferClasses: true,
    width: null
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the version you are using is not the very latest. You should check the source from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu), which is the official repository.

The version from GitHub uses **jquery.ui.position** from jQuery UI, which allows you to specify where to display the menu relatively to the element ("top top", "left bottom"...) and also **allows collision detection**.

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/#option-collision):

> When the positioned element overflows the window in some direction,
>   move it to an alternative position. Similar to my and at, this accepts
>   a single value or a pair for horizontal/vertical, eg. "flip", "fit",
>   "fit flip", "fit none".

So you'd rather use the plugin this way:

```
$('#myelement').selectmenu({
    ...
    position: {
        my: "left top", // default
        at: "left bottom", // default

        // "flip" will show the menu opposite side if there
        // is not enough available space

        collision: "flip"  // default is ""
    }
});
```

Check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197074/jquery-ui-selectmenu-dropdown-opens-up-instead-of-down/8210093#8210093) for similar problem explained (the method `_refreshPosition()` seems to not exist anymore as is but the option position is of course still there).

Comment: Hi, when i use the new jquery.ui.select.js i get this error: jquery.ui.select.js:46 - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_bind' - In my first post i have add my JS.

Comment: The plugins is based in jQuery UI 1.9 (still in dev !) in which the Widget Factory implements the `_bind()` method. You have to use jQuery UI 1.9.

Comment: Will everyting work when i use this version? Because i use the UI for more plugins...

Comment: How would I know ? :-) Your best bet is to test your site against this new version and see if everything works as expected, this is totally *at your own risk*. A lot of the plugins are being code redesigned so there is a risk for sure.

Comment: Mmm i not gonna use the beta version of UI because i am busy for some clients, but thank you for your help. I hope there will be another fix for it.